# Transient BackgroundService, the instance that is returned is always different?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, background-service, transient

So I have a scenario where i have to execute several tasks in parallel, i have a class with a generic type that inherits from a **BackgroundService**, that will be responsible for executing a single task. For each task i want a new instance to perform the given task. The goal is to have a pool of workers.

```
Worker<T>:BackgroundService
```

In the startup I add it as follows:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(Worker<>));
```

My question is, when i ask the **ServiceProvider** for a new instance, the instance that is returned is always different?

Comment: Register as singleton then you will have same instance.

Comment: @FlorimMaxhuni maybe i have explained me wrong, the goal is to have a pool of workers executing tasks. What i want to know is if ask for a new instance what is returned is actually a new instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is, when i ask the ServiceProvider for a new instance, the instance that is returned is always different?

Yes, that's the point of being "transient". "Scoped" returns same instance within the scope (in ASP.NET Core during one request) and "Singleton" is same instance always.

However, if your transient service has scoped dependencies, these may not always be same (depending if you resolve inside the scope or not). You should avoid having scoped dependencies for transient services.

If you have scoped services and you can't have them transient, you gotta create a scope. That could happen by spinning a task, resolving the `IServiceScopeFactory`, resolving the services you need, call them, then dispose the scope (which dispose all of its scoped and transient dependencies)

```
var scopeFactory = _serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
     var myService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Worker<MyT>>();
}
```

Comment: @Tseng, what happens inside the worker is that this receives a configuration and with that creates an object that performs a http request based on the configuration received. For this scenario the scopedServices is necessary or the Transient is enough? Thank you for the help.

Comment: For `HttpClient` you don't need scoped services. But if your worker resolves multiple services which need to have a shared instanced (i.e. `DbContext` for transactions), then you **may** have to